# Virtualizing networking appliance with qemu or similar

Tags: arm, virtual-machine, openwrt

Since I'm interested in some *WRT/OpenWRT related work on ARM devices, I would like to use some virtualized environment for this and for facilitate my tasks.

A more direct question will be: it's possible to install [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) under an ARM virtualized environment with features similar to a commercial router ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently as you know that there are projects with [**OpenWRT on ARM**](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/seagate/dockstar#building.openwrt.for.the.dockstar).

Besides that from buildroot you can choose a wide range of ARM MPU, to build a new distribution, there are also some commercial SoC projects like [**this**](http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/).

Well! *Do you can virtualize these images with similar features and good performance?*

**Sure!** The performance is decided by the host machine and also the available network hardware.

For the software there are several network-bridge strategy allowing Qemu virtualization have almost every feature you can find inside a dedicated hardware.

[**Here**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/topic/liaat/liaatbptap.htm) another link about a good implementation of these network-bridges on Qemu.

Comment: i'm mastering OpenWRT already, I'm not interested on how to get started with OpenWRT, I'm interested about how to master OpenWRT with Qemu

Comment: Yes sir, I have imagined you had experience with OpenWRT,and for this very reason I voted positively your question, the answer I tried, favoring three links, which allow a general approach and also useful to other users without their knowledge, and also I have focused on answering to your question, "if you can have similar features in emulation", according to my personal experience with routerboards,  I have answered it if you can.

Comment: And in the last link I've provided, you can get your information as set your "TAP" to get good performance in emulation.
I guess that you know how to launch a kernel compiled in QEMU, but
I do not know if you want to emulate an ARM SoC or an ARM MPU, I hope not to offend your knowledge if I pass a generic link on implementation of an [ARM core emulation using QEMU](http://wiki.embeddednirvana.org/ARM_Emulation_Using_QEMU). ...I just try to be helpful